# Windows 7 slow to shutdown and startup

Tags: windows-7, boot

My computer has regressed over time in performance. Maybe it's because I have installed a lot of programs I'm not sure but the operating system is slow to shut down.

I get a message waiting for background programs to close and it was explorer.exe. As matter fact explorer.exe is really causing issues in the operating system.

Crashing frequently, hogging resources, it's frustrating! What is wrong with the operating system? I know Windows 7 is not perfect operating system but is this normal?

---

Regressed is not right word sorry. Actually windows 7 performs reasonably well it's just when it starts up or shutdowns it takes more time now then ever before. I guess it's normal when I first installed the os it started up and shutdown in no time.

My current system specs

Case: Enermax Ostrog GT ATX Mid Tower ECA3280A-BR

CPU: i7 4790K

Motherboard: Asus Z97 Deluxe

Ram: Crucial CRBLS16K1280 16GB

Hard Drives: WD10EZEX 00BN5A0 1 TB HDD and PNY CS1311 256 GB SSD

Blu Ray Drive: WH16NS40

Power Supply: EVGA 650 G2

Video Card: Sapphire Vapor X R9 290 4GB

OS: Windows 7 64Bit

Water Cooler: Corsair H105

Monitor: Acer H257HU

Comment: It is normal windows slows by the time. Fix is to reinstall windows

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 v1511 SDK: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771 which is the last version that works in Win7), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Reboot Cycle**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot/shutdown. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0. Zip the ETL files into 1 zip/RAR file, upload the zip to my Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/request/9WZYVqDALKWiAsMYZelK) and post the share link here.

Comment: I'm new here so how do I get email notifications for new posts? Sorry I'll just add comment not post new answer.

Comment: click on your profile -> Edit Profile & Settings and under Preferences you can enable emails.

Comment: have you captured the traces?

Comment: For Shutdown:  Instead of troubleshooting it, here's a tip:  `REGEDIT` then go to `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management` - find the key `ClearPageFile at Shutdown`  and set it to 0.  It can make a big difference.  Also, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control` - find key `WaitToKillServiceTimeout` and set it to 1000.  Those two changes may change you mind about asking why.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "Maybe it's because I have installed a lot of programs...", it makes me wonder if you ever cleaned up programs and services starting up without being needed.
Run MSCONFIG
Go to the service tab and check "Hide all Microsoft services"
Clean up the list from services you don't need. Or disable them all to test for specific issues.
Go to the Startup tab and disable all programs you don't need to start when booting.

For a good summary of things to do to clean up the system, check out:
https://superuser.com/a/492343/652374

Comment: Yes, some housekeeping would probably be a solution for this problem ... But, why not also Windows' disk cleaning procedure, and also chkdsk /f or maybe rather even /r .

Answer (score -1):

Good News everyone. I found out the culprit that was slowing down the os. It was this strange file called sqlwriter.exe. It was located in roaming app data folder and I deleted it. Since I deleted the file the os is noticeably faster. It did not appear to be a virus, it was some file from Microsoft that somehow got on my computer perhaps through windows update I guess. Glad I solved issue :)

Comment: `sqlwriter.exe` is connected to VSS.  By removing it you have basically remove your ability to keep shadow copies of your files.  Instead of removing it just disable shadow copies feature.